# Microsoft Lync colospaces for DirecShow

Tags: winapi, directshow, lync, color-space, pixelformat

I'm developping a DirectShow filter which will act as an adapter between my ip camera and Microsoft Lync.

I'm not sure what colorspaces formats are supported.

Any clue on where I can find such information?

Answer (score -1):

The best you can do is to mimic web cameras, which are "true" (typical non-virtual) video sources in DirectShow. The best color spaces are 24-bit RGB and [Recommended 8-Bit YUV Formats...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, the most important is the preference of the application you are targeting, that is Lync. It might be requesting or preferring specific color space/pixel format. You should be seeing this with debugging.